# deploying qt quick application to android fail

Tags: android, qt, api, deployment, qml

I'm trying to deploy an application to my android device (`android version 4.4.4`) and I'm using the kit: `Android for armeabi-v7a(GCC 4.9,QT5.8.0)` and i get the following error :

```
Invalid json output from qmlimportscanner.
13:19:33: Le processus "D:\Qt5.8.0_android\5.8\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" s'est terminé avec le code 4.
Erreur lors de la compilation/déploiement du projet untitled5 (kit : Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.8.0))
```

When executing step "Build Android APK" [image: Error_Image]

I don't understand how APIs work so I literaly don't know any way to fix this.

Comment: Did you set JDK, SDK, NDK, Ant directory right ?

Comment: please insert compilation log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i did set the JDK SDK NDK well and the problem was the whitespace in the name of the folder i was using as a directory , so if anyone has the same problem please check the path of the directory you are using it MUST NOT contain any spaces , thank you aghilpro for the answer